# IndexingError: Too many indexers in a function

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to diagnose the following error: `IndexingError: Too many indexers`.
I following solutions already on stack overflow doesn't resolve my issue.

Here is my simplified code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def foo(T=None,*c):
    A = df.loc[c][0]
    B = df.loc[c][1]
    C = df.loc[c][2]
    return (10**(A-((B)/(T+C))))*760   

file = r'C:\Users\ayubi\Documents\Python Files\Chemical Engineering Files\T-xy_Data.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(file)
df_adj = df.set_index('Component')
print(df_adj)

compOne = df_adj.loc['Benzene']

foo(25,*compOne)
```

The reason why i have the function `foo` arguments in that order is if T is not given, I will be able to use fsolve.

Here is the error:

```
runcell(0, 'C:/Users/ayubi/Documents/Python Files/Chemical Engineering Files/test_example.py')
                 A        B        C
Component                           
Benzene    6.87987  1196.76  219.161
Toluene    6.95087  1342.31  219.187
Water      8.07131  1730.63  233.426
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\ayubi\Documents\Python Files\Chemical Engineering Files\test_example.py", line 24, in <module>
    foo(25,*compOne)

  File "C:\Users\ayubi\Documents\Python Files\Chemical Engineering Files\test_example.py", line 12, in foo
    A = df.loc[c][0]

  File "C:\Users\ayubi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 873, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_tuple(key)

  File "C:\Users\ayubi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1049, in _getitem_tuple
    self._has_valid_tuple(tup)

  File "C:\Users\ayubi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 700, in _has_valid_tuple
    raise IndexingError("Too many indexers")

IndexingError: Too many indexers
```

The function should be able to take the arguments `T`, if given, and `compOne` and grab the value associated with `compOne` then calculate something.
Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Did you try to check what the value of `compOne` is when the error occurs? Does it make sense to you? Why or why not? Could you show some examples of how you expect to call the function with hard-coded values, and what you expect to happen as a result? It's unclear what you're trying to accomplish by using *args here.

Comment: According to the `scipy.optimization` documentation for `fsolve`, the format is `func(x,*args)`. Hence, if x isn't given, I was going to use `fsolve`.

Comment: The documentation does **not** mean that your `func` has to accept any number of \*args. It means that your `func` needs to accept *at least one* arg (which `fsolve` will supply, starting with the provided `x0` and making adjustments as it solves), and possibly more (which it will provide from the `args` that you pass in). That is, `func`  only needs to be able to handle the extra args *that you pass in*; if you don't pass any, it doesn't need to take any.